# Android notification regarding database

Tags: android, mysql, android-notifications

I am having a service that periodically connects to a server and gets records from that and insert those into my local database everything works fine what the problem is my UI doesn't reflect the changes in my database i heard about some notification in IOS that will notify regarding changes in databases to the UI so that we can handle the refreshing events by handling those notifications . Is anything available in android similar to this ....?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial on Handler by Lars Vogel - http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

This may be what you need depends on what you are trying to do in your app.

Comment: thanks @Glorithm i tried handlers... But it's not usefull for me any way thanks for you reply